# Gradle exception for cargo plugin

Tags: gradle, cargo

My `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
```

`cargoRunLocal` is not working. It shows exception as below:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:67)
        at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:95)
        at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:97)
        at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':cargoStartLocal'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:70)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':cargoStartLocal'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:53)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.property.PropertyDataType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.local.CargoStartLocal_Decorated.getConfigHomeDir(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:453)
        at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:168)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:451)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator$1.call(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:255)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext$BuildableFileTreeInternalConverter.convertInto(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveNested(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext$BuildableFileTreeInternalConverter.convertInto(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsBuildables(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.addDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$3.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:63)
        ... 63 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.property.PropertyDataType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1381)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.property.PropertyDataType.$INIT(PropertyDataType.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.property.PropertyDataType.<clinit>(PropertyDataType.groovy)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedField.getProperty(CachedField.java:51)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1533)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3308)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.property.LocalContainerTaskProperty.<clinit>(LocalContainerTaskProperty.groovy)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedField.getProperty(CachedField.java:51)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1533)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3308)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.CargoPlugin$_configureLocalContainerConventionMapping_closure2_closure13.doCall(CargoPlugin.groovy:83)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.CargoPlugin$_configureLocalContainerConventionMapping_closure2_closure13.doCall(CargoPlugin.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        ... 102 more
    [sts] Time taken: 0 min, 0 sec
    [sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you please at least add your build.gradle or make any other efford to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is built using gradle 2.1 and needs this version to run.  You are using gradle 1.10 and this version is not compatible with the plugin.